# Can't access web server hosted on docker container (Mac M1)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elixir, apple-m1

I installed docker-desktop and I can build/start containers with no issue on my macbook m1. However I tried to serve an elixir web server, with the following `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`:

```
FROM hexpm/elixir:1.14.5-erlang-25.3.2.4-debian-buster-20230612-slim as builder

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential curl \
  && curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /pescarte

RUN mix local.hex --force && \
  mix local.rebar --force

ARG MIX_ENV=prod

COPY mix.exs mix.lock ./

# copy all mix.exs from umbrella apps
# to corresponding folder
COPY apps/catalogo/mix.exs ./apps/catalogo/
COPY apps/cotacoes/mix.exs ./apps/cotacoes/
COPY apps/cotacoes_etl/mix.exs ./apps/cotacoes_etl/
COPY apps/database/mix.exs ./apps/database/
COPY apps/identidades/mix.exs ./apps/identidades/
COPY apps/modulo_pesquisa/mix.exs ./apps/modulo_pesquisa/
COPY apps/plataforma_digital/mix.exs ./apps/plataforma_digital/
COPY apps/plataforma_digital_api/mix.exs ./apps/plataforma_digital_api/
COPY apps/proxy_web/mix.exs ./apps/proxy_web/
COPY apps/seeder/mix.exs ./apps/seeder/


RUN mix deps.get --only $MIX_ENV
RUN mix deps.compile

# to be re-compiled.
COPY config/config.exs config/${MIX_ENV}.exs config/

# compile static and dynamic assets
COPY apps/plataforma_digital/priv ./apps/plataforma_digital/priv
COPY apps/plataforma_digital/assets ./apps/plataforma_digital/assets
RUN ["npm", "ci", "--prefix", "./apps/plataforma_digital/assets/"]

# copy source code and static files
COPY apps/catalogo/lib ./apps/catalogo/lib
COPY apps/cotacoes/lib ./apps/cotacoes/lib
COPY apps/cotacoes_etl/lib ./apps/cotacoes_etl/lib
COPY apps/database/lib ./apps/database/lib
COPY apps/seeder/lib ./apps/seeder/lib
COPY apps/proxy_web/lib ./apps/proxy_web/lib
COPY apps/identidades/lib ./apps/identidades/lib
COPY apps/modulo_pesquisa/lib ./apps/modulo_pesquisa/lib
COPY apps/plataforma_digital/lib ./apps/plataforma_digital/lib
COPY apps/plataforma_digital_api/lib ./apps/plataforma_digital_api/lib

COPY apps/cotacoes/priv ./apps/cotacoes/priv
COPY apps/identidades/priv ./apps/identidades/priv
COPY apps/modulo_pesquisa/priv ./apps/modulo_pesquisa/priv

# Compile the release
RUN mix compile

# Changes to config/runtime.exs don't require recompiling the code
COPY config/runtime.exs config/

FROM builder as dev

ARG MIX_ENV="dev"

WORKDIR /pescarte

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends inotify-tools

COPY config/test.exs ./config/
COPY /apps/cotacoes/test ./apps/cotacoes/test
COPY /apps/identidades/test ./apps/identidades/test
COPY /apps/modulo_pesquisa/test ./apps/modulo_pesquisa/test
COPY /apps/plataforma_digital/test ./apps/plataforma_digital/test
COPY /apps/plataforma_digital_api/test ./apps/plataforma_digital_api/test

RUN mix deps.get
RUN mix do deps.compile, compile

CMD ["mix", "phx.server"]

FROM builder as production

WORKDIR /pescarte
RUN chown nobody /pescarte

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping libstdc++6 \
    openssl libncurses5 locales postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && sed -i 's/^# *\(en_US.UTF-8\)/\1/' /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

# set runner ENV
ENV MIX_ENV="prod"

COPY rel rel
RUN mix assets.deploy
RUN mix release && mv /pescarte/_build/${MIX_ENV}/rel/pescarte ./

USER nobody

CMD ["bin/server"]
```

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  pescarte:
    build:
      context: .
      target: dev
      args:
        - MIX_ENV=dev
    image: pescarte
    command: ["iex", "-S",  "mix", "dev"]
    container_name: plataforma_pescarte
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file:
      - .env-sample
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      MIX_ENV: dev
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  database:
    image: postgres:14.6
    container_name: plataforma_pescarte_database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=peapescarte
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=peapescarte
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - .postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U peapescarte -d peapescarte" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 2s
      retries: 1
```

So I try to see what ports are being exposed:

```
$ lsof -n -i :4000 | ag LISTEN
com.docke 93320 zoedsoupe  166u  IPv6 0x9fe6a88390b0ccd      0t0  TCP *:terabase (LISTEN)

$ lsod -n -i :5432 | ag LISTEN
com.docke 93320 zoedsoupe  186u  IPv6 0x9fe6a88390aa4cd      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

So my web server and postgresql are being exposed to host. Then I try to connect to the database:

```
$ psql -h localhost -U peapescarte
Password for user peapescarte:
psql (15.3, server 14.6 (Debian 14.6-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

peapescarte=#
```

Success! Trying finally to reach my web server:

```
$ curl http://localhost:4000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Empty response, which means that on my browser I can't access it too. The server is being exposed on `http://localhost:4000` as can be seen on the container logs:

```
plataforma_pescarte           | [info] Running ProxyWeb.Endpoint with Bandit 0.7.7 at 127.0.0.1:4000 (http)
plataforma_pescarte           |
plataforma_pescarte           | [info] Access ProxyWeb.Endpoint at http://localhost:4000
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: You dockerfile confuses me... first you compile the app in `dev` environment and run the server like you would locally and then you make a release in the with `prod` env and run this too? Plus in the compose you do `["iex", "-S",  "mix", "dev"]` No idea whats actually running here. Ahh yea in the `dev` part of the dockerfile you copy all the test files? Have you tried checking whats going on in the container with `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash` .

Comment: I split the Dockerfile into stages to be able to ru. the same Dockerfile into prod and dev envs. In the docker-compose i reference only the dev stage. And yes, the server is running correctly inside the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should bind the web server to the IP 0.0.0.0 (which makes it available to all network interfaces including localhost) because in MacOS, Docker is running inside a virtual machine.